# Limiting object tracking area using tracking js

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality

Looking to limit the area of the scan of a object tracker using the tracking js library.

e.g. i want to get the object tracker to only look for objects within a select area of the camera video feed it's pick up on and then place whatever on the canvas based on the tracking information obtained.

currently the object tracker is scanning the enitre video and then placing rects on the canvas where the objects have been found, what i want to do is have the object tracker limited to a smaller area and then place the rects on the canvas.

any ideas?

```
var fTrack = {
                faceTracking: function() {
                var face = new tracking.ObjectTracker('face');

                face.setInitialScale(3);
                face.setStepSize(1);
                face.setEdgesDensity(0.1);

                    guiup.gui(face);               

                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.lineWidth = "6";
                    ctx.strokeStyle = "#fff";
                    ctx.rect((placehold.width/2 - (500/2)), (placehold.height/2 - (600/2)), 500, 600);  
                    ctx.stroke();
                    ctx.font = "30px Comic Sans MS";
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
                    ctx.textAlign = "center";
                    ctx.fillText("Place face within box",placehold.width/2,770);


            var faceTracker = tracking.track('#video', face, {camera:true});//{ camera: true });


                face.on('track', function(event) {

                context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

                if(!event.data) return;

            event.data.forEach(function(rect) { //Replace code here to do something else once working correctly

                //draw basic rectangle around face colour black
                context.strokeStyle = '#fff';
                context.strokeRect(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height);
                // select size of font
                context.font = '11px Helvetica';
                //font colour
                context.fillStyle = "#fff";
                //text to be displayed around face rectangle(will be displayed on the right)
                context.fillText('x: ' + rect.x + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 11); // to show xpx
                context.fillText('y: ' + rect.y + 'px', rect.x + rect.width + 5, rect.y + 22); // to show ypx
```

Comment: track(pixels, width, height)
    Tracks the pixels on the array. This method is called for each video frame in order to emit `track` event.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just check the position of the rect inside the last forEach function.

And only draw react inside your area

Comment: Hi, this is a comment and isn't a right answer to the question.

Comment: as some of the rects are incorrect this wouldn't be viable, want i want to do is limit the location of which the object tracker can scan e.g. '#video' the camera feed is 800x600 but i want to only scan the location of a certain part of the camera feed.

Comment: @jecorrales i'm not sure about that, by looking at the tracking.js API, there seem to be no way to do what the OP is asking without modifying the plugin. This answer is a very simple way to obtain what the OP wants, at least gets my esteem by thinking out of the box. It could be extended with some code though

Comment: @kaddath agree with the thinking out of the box, and if the rects were pin point i'd be all over it, i guess i'm just going to have to modify the libray and do a work around.

Comment: @B.C can you add precisions about these incorrect rects? maybe you have 2 different problems (sort of XY problem) here

Comment: Another solution can be to crop the video inside another canvas and do the tracking on the cropped canvas

Comment: @TristanDeoliveira that's a really good idea! will test that out, thank you :)